# session doesn't work in mail verification register

Tags: php, session, session-variables

i use email verification for my registration.
after register i login user and keep it's id in session (i have a session class for storing user login info) and then send a link to his mail and after all i redirect user to another page and tell him please check ur mail and click....

this is link that i send to user mail(for now i just send to my mail by default)

```
$body.="<h4><a href='http://www.habibabdollahi.com/fani/home/activate.php?user=".$user->id.
                "&code=".$user->mail_verify_code."'>فعال سازی</a></h4>";
```

in activate.php i verify user with his id and his code but it seem i dont access the session after click link in the mail.
but if if redirect user after register to the activate.php like the last link there is no problem and i have session in this situation.

```
redirect_to("home/activate.php"."?user=$user->id&code=$user->mail_verify_code");
```

whats the problem friends, i'm going to be mad!

just focus on session, i just want know why my session lost after redirect via mail
and this my session class

```
class Session{

    public $user_id;
    private $loged_in=false;
    private $verified_mail=false;
    private $verified_mobile=false;
    private $user_type; 


    function __construct(){
        session_start();
        $this->check_login();
        $this->check_verification();// ham mobile va ham mail ra check mikonad
        $this->check_user_type();
    }

    /* It'es get method, that get the loged status  */
    public function is_logged_in(){
        return $this->loged_in;     
    }

    public function login($user){
        //database should find user based on username and password
        if($user){
            $this->user_id=$_SESSION['user_id']=$user->id;
            $this->loged_in=true;
        }
    }

    public function verify_mobile($is_verified){
        if($is_verified){
            $this->verified=$_SESSION['verified_mobile']=$is_verified;
        }else{
            return false;   
        }
    }

    public function verify_mail($is_verified){
        if($is_verified){
            $this->verified=$_SESSION['verified_mail']=$is_verified;
        }else{
            return false;   
        }
    }
    /******  user type ra be khater miseparad    *********************/
    public function remember_user_type($user){
            if($user){
                $this->user_type=$_SESSION['user_type']=$user->user_type_id;
            }
    }
    public function get_user_type(){

        return $this->user_type;    
    }


    private function check_user_type(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_type'])){
            $this->user_type=$_SESSION['user_type'];
        }

    }
    // che mobile va ya che mail verify shode bashad okeye
    public function get_is_verified(){
        return ($this->verified_mobile || $this->verified_mail);
    }

    public function get_is_verified_mobile(){
        return $this->verified_mobile;      
    }

    public function get_is_verified_mail(){
        return $this->verified_mail;        
    }

    public function logout(){
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($this->user_id);
        $this->loged_in=false;
    }

    public function get_user_id(){
        return $this->user_id;  
    }

    private function check_login(){

        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
            $this->user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
            $this->loged_in=true;

        }else{
            unset($this->user_id);
            $this->loged_in=false;
        }

    }//check_login

    private function check_verification(){

        if(isset($_SESSION['verified_mail'])){
            $this->verified_mail=$_SESSION['verified_mail'];
            //$this->verified=true; 
        }

        if(isset($_SESSION['verified_mobile'])){
            $this->verified_mobile=$_SESSION['verified_mobile'];
            //$this->verified=true;
        }

    }


}//class end

$session=new Session();
//var_dump($session);
```

Comment: Well, sessions are temporary things, the registered user may not check the emial after even a long time, you need to store the information in the database for sure!

Comment: @someOne i know that i just want if user click the link in the mail after the registration without closing the browser redirect to admin page without need to login again

Comment: Not clear, can you be more specific pls

Comment: when i register user i keep is_login=true in session, and after verify his mail i want redirect the user to his control panel, without need to login again.

Comment: and i know if user close his borwser i lost the session, but in case he didnt i want to redirect him immediately

Comment: Have you resumed your session using `session_start()` in your `activate.php` file?

Comment: Don't you have any problems with the _session class_ of yours? I mean, have you tested it? (considering the information provided, that's the only suspicious part.)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        $this->user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
        $this->loged_in=true;

    }
```

instead of

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['user'])){
        $this->user_id=$_REQUEST['user'];
        $this->loged_in=true;

    }
```

because of use pass `user` parameter on url

```
$body.="<h4><a href='http://www.habibabdollahi.com/fani/home/activate.php?user=".$user->id.
                "&code=".$user->mail_verify_code."'>فعال سازی</a></h4>";
```

Comment: why?i use session->login after create user and i have user id

Comment: sorry, my missunderstanding.. in above code you use 'if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
            $this->user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
            $this->loged_in=true;

        }' , but you pass 'user' parameter on url so, you use   'if(isset($_REQUEST['user'])){
            $this->user_id=$_REQUEST['user'];
            $this->loged_in=true;

        }'

Answer (score 0):

> After the verification code refresh the session and redirect the user
>   to login page When user coming for login then check if user is Active
>   then all user data is send to session Array
>   I am not Expert but give a advice
>
> first take take user identity ID which you select for login
>
> then send those ID to login function and then give him session
>
> Just try that

```
private function check_login($userID){
     Used Fetch Query there for login authentication and then give him to session ...       
your session code is here.........................  and redirect or return true   
}
```